# How to Take Input Data from Arduino to HTML and Log File?

Tags: javascript, html, arduino, johnny-five

I have found a code to make output data from HTML to Arduino by using Johnny Five. Now, I need your help to explain, how to take and save input data from Arduino to HTML and Log file (it could be plain text, xml, or another type). So that, i can processing the variable.

This is my output data maker

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
      $('#button').click(function(e){
        socket.emit('click');
        e.preventDefault();
      });
    });  
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="button" href="#">LED ON/OFF</button>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler),
     io = require('socket.io').listen(app),
     fs = require('fs'),
   five = require('johnny-five');

app.listen(8080);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

board = new five.Board();

board.on("ready", function() {
  led = new five.Led(13);

  io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('click', function () {
      led.toggle();
    });
  }); 
});
```

Now, I need your help to show some code and explain how it work